# Which is a better real time app solution? Backend django directly connecting to the sensor or reading data from database?

Tags: django, websocket, real-time, django-channels

I am developing a real time web app which will display data collected from sensor in browser. But it seems to be 2 ways to do it. On the frontend I am using Angular 4. And on the backend I am using django.

First way is using Django to create a socket client and connect to the sensor dada collector (which is a raspberry pi) directly. On the raspberry pi there is a socket server listened on it. Once the django connects to raspberry pi, raspberry pi will push data to the socket. Then django can push data to frontend angular 4 using websocket (by django channels).

Second way is running a standalone python socket client script connecting to the raspberry pi socket server and saving data into the database. Backend django will query the database every seconds and get the latest data. Then using websocket to push the data to frontend angular 4 in the same way as first way.

Which is a better solution?

Comment: I am developing a similar project and would like to know the answer, too. Did you find out anything new since this post? Thank you!

Comment: @Bohr Now I use the second way with some changes. For example, the sockets were only used to send and receive data, the django channels or celery was used to save data to database and send data to websocket. On the frontend, angular will query the history data using the http. And the live data will be updated by websocket.